# Python: If/elif/else Statement Not Working as Expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, valueerror

So I have the user input an expression:

**Example**:

```
1 + 1
d * 3
100 / j
s * c
```

To allow the user to mix numbers (int) and letters (str) I have the following if statement:

```
user_input = input("Enter a math Equation: ")
user_input = user_input.strip().split(" ")
user_c1 = user_input[0]
user_c2 = user_input[2]
user_c3 = user_input[1]
l1 = user_c1
l2 = user_c2
l3 = user_c2
l6 = user_c1
l4 = int(user_c2)
l5 = int(user_c1)
l7 = int(user_c1)
l8 = int(user_c2)


if l1 and l2 in kb_dxnry:
    print("1st")
elif l3 in kb_dxnry and l4 not in kb_dxnry:
    print("2nd")
elif l5 not in kb_dxnry and l6 in kb_dxnry:
    print("3rd")
else:
    print("4th")
```

**Dictionary Code**

```
user_kb_dxnry = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6,
                 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, "k": 11, "l": 12,
                 "m": 13, "n": 14, "o": 15, "p": 16, "q": 17, "r": 18,
                 "s": 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24,
                 'y': 25, 'z': 26, "0": 0
                 }
kb_dxnry = user_kb_dxnry
```

If I type (well testing it): 1 + 1 it will execute the else statement (as it should). However, if you type any of the other combinations:

```
a + a
1 + a
a + 1
```

It ignores the if and elif statements and tries to executes else & failes.

So I type

```
23 * 23
```

**Output**:

4th

I type

```
a + 1 or a + a or 1 * a
```

**Output is**:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

So my if statement is failing and being new to (programming in general) I was wondering if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do above. Maybe something I've over looked or under looked?

Would a for be better suited or would it give me the same error?

**Feel free to link me to any thing you think could be helpful in helping me get this working.**

**EDIT:**

Perhaps this would be better:

```
user_input = input("Enter a math Equation: ")
    user_input = user_input.strip().split(" ")
    user_c1 = user_input[0]
    user_c2 = user_input[2]
    user_c3 = user_input[1]
    l1 = user_c1
    l2 = user_c2
    l3 = user_c2
    l6 = user_c1
   user_input = input("Enter a math Equation: ")
user_input = user_input.strip().split(" ")
user_c1 = user_input[0]
user_c2 = user_input[2]
user_c3 = user_input[1]
l1 = user_c1
l2 = user_c2
l3 = user_c2
l6 = user_c1
l4 = user_c2
l5 = user_c1
l7 = user_c1
l8 = user_c2


if l1 in kb_dxnry and l2 in kb_dxnry:
    print("1st")
elif l3 in kb_dxnry and l4 not in kb_dxnry:
    l4 = int(user_c2)
    print("2nd")
elif l5 not in kb_dxnry and l6 in kb_dxnry:
    l5 = int(user_c1)
    print("3rd")
else:
    l7 = int(user_c1)
    l8 = int(user_c2)
    print("4th")
```

Alright with the rewrite of code above the ErrorValue is gone. But if you type a + 1 or 1 + a

It still skips elif 1 & 2:

```
elif l3 in kb_dxnry and l4 not in kb_dxnry:
    print("2nd")
elif l6 in kb_dxnry and l5 not in kb_dxnry:
    print("3rd")
```

And jumps to else.

Comment: `if l1 and l2 in kb_dxnry:` should be `if l1 in kb_dxnry and l2 in kb_dxnry:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are making so many variables if you are only trying to process one expression.

If you look at the line number in your error statement, I bet you will see it refers to the lines where you are defining `l4, l5, l7, l7`.  You are doing `int()` conversions there and if you pass those conversions a string, you will get the error you posted, so I don't think you are even getting to your if-else statement.

Comment: Well as I explained already I needed a way to see if the user typed a possible int in the string. I thought it was quite clear what I was trying to do.

Comment: Would it be better to just check the strings being in the dictionary ( e,g, a + 1) it will look for both and if one fails it moves to the next elif and than inside the if statement than do the str to in?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out with the help of @AirSquid. I removed the str to int and search for the strings that may be numbers in the dictionary. Than in the if statement is will I will change them to int.

```
user_input = input("Enter a math Equation: ")
    user_input = user_input.strip().split(" ")
    user_c1 = user_input[0]
    user_c2 = user_input[2]
    user_c3 = user_input[1]
    l1 = user_c1
    l2 = user_c2
    l3 = user_c2
    l6 = user_c1
   user_input = input("Enter a math Equation: ")
user_input = user_input.strip().split(" ")
user_c1 = user_input[0]
user_c2 = user_input[2]
user_c3 = user_input[1]
l1 = user_c1
l2 = user_c2
l3 = user_c2
l6 = user_c1
l4 = user_c2
l5 = user_c1
l7 = user_c1
l8 = user_c2


if l1 in kb_dxnry and l2 in kb_dxnry:
    print("1st")
elif l3 in kb_dxnry:
    l4 = int(user_c2)
    print("2nd")
elif l5 not in kb_dxnry:
    l5 = int(user_c1)
    print("3rd")
else:
    l7 = int(user_c1)
    l8 = int(user_c2)
    print("4th")
```

The above code now does what I wanted it to do.